# redux handle If the propertie ID are already in the store

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

**Hello everyone**

Problem: Trying to make a cart functionality in redux

Description:

If I will add the same product in the same action I want to update the quantity available in the attribute object of array, but if I want to add the same product the quantity will be added yeah, but the same product will be added.

To respond at this problem I have made this:

```
const cart = [...store.getState()]
  cart[cart.length -1].products.map((item) => {
   if (item.productID === data.product.id){
    item.quantity++
   }
})
```

I have made this too but I prefer first solution:

```
for(let i = 0; i < cart[cart.length -1].products.length; i++){
    if (cart[cart.length -1].products[i].productID === data.product.id){
        cart[cart.length -1].products[i].attributes[0].quantity++ //findIndexFromCart
    }
}
```

I'm using this to handle if the product are in store or not but If I add an else the product will be added multiple time, I don't know how to do this logic with my code.

Full code:

```
const onClickAddToCartHandler = () => {
        if (RadioState !== undefined){
            axios.get(`attributes/${RadioState}`)
                .then(({data}) => {
                    const cart = [...store.getState()]
                    cart[cart.length -1].products.map((item) => {
                        if (item.productID === data.product.id){
                            item.quantity++
                        }
                    })

                    store.dispatch({
                        type: ADD_PRODUCT_TO_CART_ACTION,
                        payload: {
                            productID: data.product.id,
                            attributes: [
                                {
                                    id: RadioState,
                                    price: data.price,
                                    quantity: 1
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    })
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    console.log(err)
               })
        }
    }
```

Comment: We might need you to get some help with your English. I'm struggling with some of that.

Comment: Sorry French people trying to talk English

Comment: But if u know my code, that I can explain to you, is if I'm trying to add the same product with the same action in the store, I will have an unique product and just update the quantity